# osx application which has a button that sets the user's background as their screensaver

Tags: objective-c, macos, background, screensaver, nstask

im making an osx application which has a button that sets the user's background as their screensaver. here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)startSaver:(id)sender {     

    NSTask *task;     
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];     
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/open"];          
    NSArray *arguments;     
    arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-a", (@"/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background"), nil];     
    [task setArguments: arguments];          
    [task launch]; 
}
```

for some reason i keep getting this error:
    `FSPathMakeRef(/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background) failed with error -43.`

please help!!

Comment: `-(IBAction)startSaver:(id)sender;` Looks like a semicolon that's out of place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  [File Manager Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000107-CH5g-RCM0037)

> fnfErr    -43 File or directory not found; incomplete pathname.

`/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background` path doest exist.

you can also use system command:

```
system("/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background");
```

using NSTask:

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine"];
NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"-background"];
[task setArguments: arguments];
[task launch];
```

Comment: thanks the system command works! unfortunately when the command is launched my application freezes :( any ideas?

Comment: system is blocking call.

Comment: what do you mean system is blocking the call?  when i press the button it works in setting my screensaver as my background

Comment: system() function is blocking. use & at the end of command. system("/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background &"); this will fork your command.